# Consuming an OData request in Sencha Touch with JSONP

Tags: jsonp, odata, sencha-touch

I'm working on a Sencha Touch app and I want to use OData so I have been playing around with the netflix Odata service. When I send my request with JSONP in Sencha I can see the request come back when I trace it, however my callback function is never getting called. Can anyone help? Here is my code.

```
var blah = function () {
    Ext.util.JSONP.request({
        url: 'http://odata.netflix.com/catalog/Titles()',
        callbackKey: 'callback',
        params: {
            $format: 'json',
            $top: '10',
            $filter: "startswith(Name,'C')",
            $select: "ShortName"
        },
        callback: function (result) {
            alert('asdf');
            var data = result;
            if (data) {
                alert('data');
            } else {
                alert('There was an error during retrieving data.');
            }
        }
    });
}

var button = new Ext.Button({
    text: 'Ajax',
    listeners: {
        'tap': blah
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have tried to test your code, but the JSON data that is returned causes an "error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :". This could be one of the reasons why your callback isn't firing (the data is loaded, but there is an 'exception'. Does the JSON come back without any errors on your end?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a syntax error on the server response quotes, this is a known issue described [here](http://datajs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Frequently%20Asked%20Questions#x_x_x_x_x_x_x_x_x_x_x_x_x_window-json-parse) for which there is an available update.

Answer (score 0):

The server is returning XML, not JSON data.